# Request for Coaching System

Tags: feature-request, help

There are 598,010 questions with no answers at the moment.

Some of them have problems with clarity, and some are too challenging.

Most of them are answerable with some clarifications and some with splitting the problem into two.

Some are better to close.

It would be nice to be a mentor for some people here.

This means that they get notifications about the progress of these people regularly, such as about their questions that have been down-voted or received no answers.
I have today launched about 10 bounties in my different Stack Exchange accounts for other people.
I think this kind of behavior should be encouraged in some way.
Probably, better and more coaching tags, at least, should be thought of and made.

I propose to make a plan for building a coaching system for users here.
It is an entirely voluntary choice to use it.
And it should be agreed by both users that he is the coach/mentor of this user.

Comment: The focus is pretty much on the content here, rather than individual users. Just do what you can already do; comment, edit, vote, etc.

Comment: Your feature request is a bit vague.  What would such a coaching system look like?  Most unanswered questions with zero votes that are more than 1 year old should probably just be deleted, and there isn't much point to specifically mentoring users with questions more than about six to eight weeks old.

Comment: The intentions of this are good, but my estimate is that most of those 598,010 questions have been abandoned, or their authors simply don't care. There is a million better ways for talented people to spend their time improving the world

Comment: "I propose to make a plan for building a coaching system for users here." -- the great thing about how Stack Overflow is built is that it doesn't take *us* to come up with all of its features. :) Instead of proposing making a plan, you can skip ahead to proposing the feature you want to see. How would you want it to work? Who would be able to use it? Flesh this out and your ideas can be vetted here by other users and the SE team.

Comment: I like the idea of a Stack Overflow mentoring site, but as Anna says the proposal needs much more detail. If you want add that, [this site](http://phpmentoring.org/) might give you some ideas.

Comment: @AnnaLear I have no idea how it can work. The problem which I want to target is to decrease the amount of unanswered questions. Make a plan how to decrease the amount. Either close, delete or clarify. One way is to encourage others to boost other users. Another way is to allow user to get updates of the other user by mail by some time interval.

Comment: Related: [Mentorship Research Project - Results + Wrap-Up](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357198/mentorship-research-project-results-wrap-up), SO tag [mentoring](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mentoring)

Comment: Related: [Staging Ground](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/staging-ground/info) (2022/2023)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm sure there are many great individuals out there that would benefit from such a mentoring program. People who simply don't know how to express a problem, perhaps ones who haven't had the luxury of a comfy education in a rich country, don't have the free time to learn stuff on the side, have three jobs, etc. People who work hard on becoming better programmers and could use a bit of a orientation from an experienced, kind tutor.

However, for every one of those individuals, there is going to be a hundred that

- Simply don't know anything about programming - at all
- Have a blog / site / shop, know nothing about programming, and are too cheap / can't afford to hire a programmer
- Students that are too lazy to work through their assignments (you'd be surprised)
- People who accepted a gig / job *far* beyond their abilities, and now rely on Stack Overflow to fix every single problem they encounter (you'd be surprised)
- People who [just want the codez](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/plz-email-me-teh-codez.aspx)
- [Help vampires](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/)

These are problems that no tutor can solve, but an offer of individual tutoring would very likely be flooded with requests for help from those, much more often than the "good" ones. This would  eventually (very quickly) frustrate the volunteers donating their time.

Stack Overflow's model is great because it *doesn't* emphasize an individual connection between asker and answerer... that said, I wouldn't be surprised if portals connecting tutors and tutees already exist. And there are other means for talented programmers to use their powers for good, let me see whether I can dig up the related Q&A from a while back.

Edit: here's some generic pointers for programmers with social causes. I'm not completely blown away by either resource, but I'm sure there's more around.

- http://socialcoder.org/
- [How can programming ability be used to help people in poverty?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/47558/how-can-programming-ability-be-used-to-help-people-in-poverty)
- [How can I use my coding skills for good?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58533/how-can-i-use-my-coding-skills-for-good)

Comment: I couldn't agree with you more. This sums up all the people who ask questions here. As for the one's that would benefit from a 'coach system', I believe they are fine so long as they show interest and learn the SO model. They will pick everything up fast enough, and eventually be helping others here.

Comment: Mentors can weed out the lazy very quickly, by setting homework.

Comment: @halfer I doubt whether that would work without a formal framework - a contract that both sides agree on. Given that the initial situation is a question that no one understands, I wouldn't be too optimistic on that.

Comment: @Probably, you're right that more detail would be required. I'm presuming mentors and students would meet up with an electronic whiteboard and voice/text chat, and that the setting of weekly homework would be a great way to weed out timewasters at an early stage.

Comment: @halfer that could work - but feels off-mission for Stack Overflow and its culture to me. I wonder whether something like it already exists in the huge space of startups and social web x.0 ventures out there

Comment: You misunderstood me. The point is not to build person-to-person system. The point is to minimise the amount of unanswered questions either by closing, deleting or clarifying. One thing which I proposed is to encourage existing users to boost others. If other people are not reacting to your encouragements, then just leave it and vote to close. So no person-person relationships.

Comment: @Masi but then you can already do that with the functions currently available to you, can't you? Nothing new would need to happen.

Comment: @Bart Yes, I can. I am just worried about the huge number of unanswered questions, which seem to be increasing. I would like to consider a plan how to decrease it some. Probably, we can have a campaign or something to decrease it. Or think more badges for those who manage to activate some users or something.

Comment: @Masi I wouldn't so much focus on numbers. Just lead by example. Participate in reviews. Edit. Leave constructive comments, etc.

Comment: @Bart Yes, that I am doing. I think it is the best way for all here.

Comment: @Masi hmm, I'm not sure whether the number of unanswered questions is really an issue - remember that the number of *overall* questions rises as well, by more than 7,000 every day. There's always going to be *some* unanswered questions, and for many, the benefit from fixing them would likely not be worth the effort.

Comment: @probablyPekka This is true, Natural amount of unanswered questions. There are still questions that are hoped to be solved or have been forgotten. So the target would be those questions that are hoped to be solved or are too challenging or too broad. The current Review System is very good, but I think should include also those older questions sometimes. So either close or comment to those old questions.