# Reasonableness of homework questions and difficulty of beginners to ask their doubts?

Tags: discussion, homework

As I see doubts can range from too localized ones to multiple benefit ones, but often localized problems are closed or put on hold... Localized problems are beneficial on long term...

I don't know why questions especially the homework questions that haven't being asked properly are simply declared as off topic and put on hold. Phrases are really important? This is what I can understand. Beginners are really facing problems to uphold their doubts.

My question wasn't over whether beginners could ask a good question or not.or whether they get many upvotes or not. I just told that beginners are not adapted to ask questions in the style.

For e.g. homework questions are asked in a fashion."Am I right " and not in the way
" Can you please check it". (as I read from a link) Questions can't directly be copied and pasted from text books...

But what I personally think is that solving up some textual numerical (for science-based sites) or factual questions can clear most of our concepts and doubts related to it.

I am not telling that beginners cannot ask good questions and that they cannot elaborate it. They can. But I am just saying that many of us aren't able ask a scienfic or any other questions properly perphaps. And experts/teachers are just downvoting them and giving us a link and we are reading the ans ( related to our improper way of questioning) and we aren't able to locate where our mistake lies. Mistakes are common. But among several mistakes it really difficult to locate our mistakes.

As we all know some doubts can't really be just dotted down. So for some people (not just beginners) doubts are remaining unsolved and unclear though they putting considerable effort from their own to express it.

Comment: If you're talking about your deleted chemistry question, it looks like you were given a link to [a guide](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) on how to improve your question. Did something about that guide not help you improve your question?

Comment: related, if not a duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18242/what-is-the-policy-here-on-homework

Comment: In theory, everything you need to know to complete a homework was *already given to you* by your teacher, in either texts, lectures, or coursework. So *tell* us what you’ve already been taught, what materials you have that bear on the homework, and be very specific in *what pieces you’re missing*. You should also maintain the view that your first line of support is your teachers, texts, and fellow students, and SO is only the backup line.

Comment: @Catija i am not talking about the deleted chemistry question.  But as i was going through the physics questions. i found a question good enough.. As it would clear doubts of  most new learners regarding the topic or concepts.  But god knows why that was answered to a off topic..

Comment: If you believe a question would be helpful to future visitors (as opposed to them reading it from their textbook) you can bring it up on Physics meta and make a case for why it should be reopened. RE the second paragraph: Note that questions on Stack Exchange should ideally be 1) of a certain minimum quality, and 2) helpful to future visitors, or we'd be duplicating countless other forums. Not helpful.

Comment: The problem isn't beginner questions. On most science sites, the highest-voted questions are beginner questions (though that's a different story). The problem is that nobody _else_ could gain when a homework question is answered on the internet. You didn't elaborate on "Localized problems are beneficial on long term..." So far, the consensus is that they _aren't_, so you'll need to justify that bit.

Comment: I have edited my question,  hopefully i have made myself clear

Comment: It looks like you're asking for a [coaching system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207285/request-for-coaching-system) or [tutoring](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295647/where-does-one-go-if-a-question-is-not-good-enough-for-stack-overflow-stack-sit) and the Q/A model isn't a good fit for that. Other venues outside of SE are happy to take it. We don't need to cater for everything.

Comment: @rene To be precise my question is why check my work and homework questions are generally referred as off topic? If they are as per rules.. then how one would clear them up..

Comment: Most sites in the SE network are not to check your work, that is where a teacher is for. Keep in mind that the questions asked and answers on any SE site are not primarily meant for the asker but for the many visitors that follow in the years to come. "check my work" questions are not terrible interesting for others to read, follow or dig into to, hence they are not useful and therefor closed, down voted and deleted.

Comment: @rene thank you as that's what i wanted to know. Now i understand.. Things better. Thanks

Comment: When I first came to the stack exchange network, I looked around to get a feel for what was expected of questions, between research and formatting. Before I asked my first Question here... oh, wait, that's right, I haven't yet; I'm still looking. But most of the students here can be identified fairly quickly by their lack of following stackexchange conventions, their 1 reputation, and the fact most of them have only very recently created an account and then went straight to asking a question. Sure, students don't know much, but there's lots of student questions they could try answering first.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Being a beginner is not an excuse to ask a bad question that demonstrates minimal previous effort in researching and/or leaving out important details requiring people to repeatedly ask for clarification. In those cases, people often prefer closing such questions instead as they're usually not answerable in the state they're written as-is.

Everyone was a beginner at the start of learning something, but the principal of asking questions does not change. If you want others to help you, you must *enable* them to help you. That includes providing a minimal, complete and verifiable example (often referred to as MCVE), as well as a clear demonstration of your own understanding of the problem and what you have tried. Maybe it's really a simple misunderstanding of a concept, but without details no one can answer your question properly, people can only speculate.

That's what a bad question is. It's not as simple as a "beginner question". Sometimes beginners also ask good questions, albeit less likely IMO.

Comment: MCVE,  how would one provide that? I mean. suppose I can't understand certain phrases of a question.  So i will write the question and ask that i can't understand the underlying meaning of the quoted phrases. So please help. IS THIS HOW I CLARIFY MY DOUBT

Comment: @Sreetama I didn't know you wasn't asking about Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Sreetamaghoshhazra If you can’t understand a question set to you by your teacher, ask your teacher, or a fellow student doing the same assignment.

Comment: @DanBron I am sorry if I am impolite. But  can't we do the same here? As sometimes teacher do not set us assignments, we ourselves practice questions from books and most problems have difficult underlying concepts hidden behind .. Hence we need help. Isn't stack exchange the right platform for that? Sorry again if i am impolite.

Comment: @Sreetamaghoshhazra You are not impolite, do no worry. Short answer: SE is not the platform to learn or get help leaning something from scratch. SE is designed for people who already know the tech they’re asking about, and have a tricky technical question which isn’t covered by standard learning materials, documentation, or quick google searches. To learn something, what you really need is a dialog, a back and forth, and some dedicated hand holding, and SE’s Q&A format is really bad at facilitating that.